# Git stopped tracking files as deleted if containing folder is deleted

Tags: git

I'm having issues on a git repository on my Windows PC. Starting today, git has started ignoring file deletions if a whole folder is deleted.

Suppose I have folder F with files A and B inside. Any edit I make to the files is correctly tracked when running "git status". If I delete one of the files or both, they also show up correctly as deleted.

If instead I just delete the whole folder F, nothing shows up in git. Running "git status" says "nothing to commit, working tree clean".

If I edit file A (correctly tracked as changed), and leave file B untouched, then delete the folder F, file A is correctly tracked as deleted. Nothing about file B.

I've never seen anything like this happen and wasn't able to find any similar report online. Any help is appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Can you give a reproducible example? Tell us **exactly and specficially** what commands you executed and give us the **exact** output (if necessary obfuscated the affected file names, but make it clear if you do so).

Comment: Hi @JoachimSauer, I've executed no commands. I've given the exact explanation of what happens in the post... If I delete a random folder in the repository which contains files, then run "git status", the output is "nothing to commit, working tree clean". The delete is not tracked. If I delete any single file in the folder instead of the folder, the files are correctly tracked as deleted.

Comment: Can you reproduce this in a new git repository that you create locally (just commit a bunch of files in folders and delete them afterwards)? Or does it only happen with the one affected repo?

Comment: It sounds like a bug. Please specify: git version, platform, if you are using any specific filesystem (remove, virtual, having some synchronization such as dropbox). Try running `git status --porcelain F/B`, and share the output. Try with environment variable `GIT_TRACE=1`

Comment: Also output of `git ls-files -t F/B` could help

Comment: It seems likely that you have found a bug. This bug may have to do with file system monitoring on Windows, or it might not. A reproducer script and exact versions (of both Git and Windows) will be useful; sending them to the Git mailing list will be the most useful, since the Windows Git people read this list and fix bugs reported there.

Comment: @JoachimSauer it happens in new repos as well. Any repo on the machine really :(

Comment: @max630 git status --porcelain F/B and git ls-files -t F/B output nothing. Not using any specific filesystem. I do have dropbox and other sync software running, but the shared folders are outside of the git repos. Tried suspending Windows Defender real-time protection but it did nothing.

Comment: @torek Git version is 2.32.0.windows.1, Windows build is 19043.1110.

Comment: Ok I've got a pretty significant update. If I delete a folder then restart the PC, then run git status, the files in the folder are correctly reported as deleted. Maybe this can be of help!

Comment: Please check what is output of `git config core.fsmonitor` and does your issue reproduce if you change it to empty (`git config core.fsmonitor ""`)